# I have problem with circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I've got a BSc in Physics and passed all courses on classical mechanics, but whenever I have to face a problem concerning circular motion, I don't know why, but I'm always confused and keep having to open the book learn everything again instead of being able to do stuffs by myself. Even the high school level stuff, I tried relearning it times after times by reading classical mechanics books but I keep forgetting it after I finished. Is there anyway to fix this, maybe a book or a course or some online videos that deal with them in an easy-to-remember fashion?

Comment: Which part of circular motion exactly are you stumbling on? That may be easier to address than giving you generic references.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I cannot remember things I have no deep understanding of. And reading itself is no way to fix this. I need to think hard to connect all the ideas together, derive whole theory myself and ideally also do a lot of calculations which will manifest any superficiality in my understanding. No shortcuts, no magic books or videos, just a lot of hard work. I am not saying that good book, course or video does not help though.